# Eliminate cycles in a graph removing vertices

Tags: algorithm

does anyone here know if it's possible to eliminate all cycles in a undirected and unweighted graph (`n` vertices) removing vertices in a way the number of removed vertices is minimized, in `O(n^2)` ?

In the worst case, the graph can be a complete one.

If it's possible, how can i do it?
If it's not, why?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Take any undirected, unweigthed graph, and double up all the edges so that there's a cycle between each pair of adjacent vertices.

Now the minimum set of vertices that eliminates all cycles is also the minimum vertex cover of both the original and modified graphs.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover

Finding a minimum vertex cover is an NP-hard problem, so your problem is also NP-hard.

If you don't want to allow double edges, then you can add dummy vertices to hold the new edges and your problem still solves vertex cover.

Comment: I don't see how doubling the edges has any effect on the vertex cover, so I'm not sure why it's necessary.  Also, while removing the vertices in the cover will certainly destroy all cycles, it generally goes much to far -- it will remove all edges in the graph.  (Consider a 2-vertex, 1-edge graph: We need not delete any vertex here, but your method will delete one.)  The OP's problem is called Feedback Vertex Set.

Comment: I'm not saying that an algorithm for vertex cover can also solve to OP problem, I'm saying that an algorithm for the OP problem can also solve vertex cover.  The OP problem is therefore NP-hard as well.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't pick up that you were describing a reduction.  I'll take off my -1 in a moment, but before I +1, I'd like to see an explanation of how the dummy vertices don't "mess things up", i.e., how you can be sure that the VC avoids choosing any of them.

Comment: To solve vertex cover for a graph, for every edge x<->y, add a dummy vertex and edges x<->dummy<->y, turning every original edge into a cycle.  Then run OP algorithm to find the min vertex set that breaks all the cycles.  If it includes a dummy vertex, then you can swap it for either adjacent vertex, because removing either of those will break any cycle containing the dummy.  The resulting set of vertices is the min vertex cover of the original graph.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is called [Feedback Vertex Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedback_vertex_set), and unfortunately it's NP-hard, meaning no one knows a polynomial-time algorithm for solving it.

Comment: @beaker: I'm confused -- your claim doesn't contradict what I wrote.  For an undirected graph, being cycle-free implies it is a forest (a collection of trees), and a spanning tree is indeed a (single-tree) forest.  Actually finding a smallest-possible subset of vertices to remove from a given undirected graph so that the remaining vertices induce a forest is what is difficult.  (If we could delete *edges* instead of *vertices*, then you could simply find a minimum spanning tree and delete all other edges -- but OP asks for vertices to be removed.)

Comment: Oops, you're right. I was thinking edges removed. Apparently my reading skills failed me. :)

Comment: @beaker: No problem.  It's certainly interesting that these 2 very similar problems have very different complexities!